# Detect end of animation of last element in each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg

I have an animation of SVG paths and I would like to eg. addClass after last of element in paths is done with animation. I tried to add a callback for animate() but it doesnt work, it started when the first loop ended. then I tried .when(startAnimeDude()).then(doStuff()) but also it started at the beginning. Last thing what I tried is i == i.length -1 and also it started at the beginning( while the animation is still going). What I am missing ?
Thanks for reading.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/18yunbhk/

JS

```
var anim = function () {

    $.extend(jQuery.easing, {
        easeInOutQuad: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
            if ((t /= d / 2) < 1) return c / 2 * t * t + b;
            return -c / 2 * ((--t) * (t - 2) - 1) + b;
        }
    });

    var animeDude = function (parent, min, max, delayAnim) {
        var paths = $('svg').find('path');

        $.each(paths, function (i) {
            var totalLength = this.getTotalLength();

            $(this).css({
                'stroke-dashoffset': totalLength,
                'stroke-dasharray': totalLength + ' ' + totalLength
            });
            $(this).delay(delayAnim * i).animate({
                'stroke-dashoffset': 0
            }, {
                duration: Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min,
                easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
            });

            if (i == 12) { //12 is last element
                console.log('sad');
            }

        });
    };

    var startAnimeDude = function (parent) {
        animeDude(parent, 0, 1000, 40);
    };
    startAnimeDude($('svg'));


};
anim();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
if (i === (paths.length - 1)) {
    console.log("sad");
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsadasivan/y2dtxkfm/)**

If you want the condition to be checked only when the animation is complete, then you can write that piece of code in the callback function for animation.

```
$(this).delay(delayAnim * i).animate({
    'stroke-dashoffset': 0
}, {
        duration: Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min,
        easing: 'easeInOutQuad',
        complete: function() {
            if (i === (paths.length - 1)) { //12 is last element
               console.log('sad');
            } 
        }
});
```

Comment: thanks but it doesnt work, its the same issue... 'sad' is print out when the animation start and i need to do it when the last of element is done with animation

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Missed a -1. Edited the code and should work fine.

Comment: actually i did it with - 1... http://jsfiddle.net/4xf6g2eL/1/ when you open the console and run the snippet you can see that the 'sad' is print out while the animation is still going... i think the problem is that the each loop over every path immediately so it works right but the .delay() is creating this issue

Comment: thank you for your time rahul this one is right. i did the callback for .animate(); at a first stage of trying but obviously with some mistake. thanks again